# How to maximize the fruit yield in a small garden

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-recommendations

I have a small backyard - around 100 square meters. I want to use a part of it to plant some fruit trees. What fruit trees should I pick in order to get the maximal amount of edible fruits per year?

The following information may be relevant: the garden is in a hilly region, about 800 meters above sea level. The temperatures in the winter (in celsius) are about 5-15, with about three extreme nights where the temperature at night is below 0. The temperatures in the summer are about 20-30. The humidity is about 70% and there is a fair amount of rain, but I am going to have a computerized watering system.

EDIT: here is a plan of the garden. The garden is green and the house is blue. The numbers are in centimeters. The black discs are sewer covers.

[image]

Comment: 100 m2 are not so much, so we need more information: are you free to plant any tree (any height) also near the boundaries of your property? What are the common fruit trees near you? (to maximize yield, you need a good pollination, a single tree of one species could not be enough).

Comment: Is it humid, semi-arid, or arid (rainfall doesn't necessarily correspond with that)? Are you near a coast? What's your soil type (e.g. clay, clay loam, loam, sandy loam, sandy)?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I think I am free to plant anything also near the boundaries - the boundaries are near gardens of other neighbors or a public promenade; see the picture I added.

Comment: @Shule the humidity is between 50% and 90%, usually 70%.

Comment: Your climate is different than I'm used to, but hopefully someone more familiar will answer. You could probably grow tropical stuff there. Maybe citrus, dates, figs, pomegranates, and stuff like that. Tradewindsfruit.com probably has a lot of seeds you could grow as perennials there (most probably aren't trees, though). I'd put the most important fruit trees on the south, and the next on the west. More shade-tolerant stuff on the north.